# Returning sum of the positive values and sum of negative values in the margin column in this visual into cards

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I have this visual in power bi dashboard
[image]

I want to display the sum of all the positive values in the Margin column on the Card and the negative values in the Margin Column on another Card.
First Card is 185.64 and the second card is -375.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these 2 measures and put them on card visuals:

```
Pos Margin = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Margin ]),
    'Table'[Margin ] >= 0
)
```

```
Neg Margin = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[Margin ]),
    'Table'[Margin ] < 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter for the solution. I also want to get the count of the positive and negative margin. Please how do I go about this. I tried this Count_PosMargin = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Margin]), 'Table'[Margin]>=0).  This did not work.

Comment: I don't see why your formula shouldn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: That is what I thought as well. I think why is not working is because each of the margin in the table was an aggregation of different sales of the same dates. The result of the count I got was the count of the table of the transaction that has the margin not aggregated.